# Reorganizing outputs using grep

Tags: bash, unix, terminal, grep

I have some random inputs of numbers, like:

```
0x3000 0x80004000        # There are Many Random Strings Here#                        0x7000
0x8600 x1260       x1800 x45003045 # Random Strings #
```

So there will be a 4-digit or 8-digit number after the `x`. 
I only need to fetch the 4 Digits or 8 Digits

I want the output to be like this, one per line:

```
0x3000
0x80004000
0x7000
0x8600
x1260
x1800
x45003045
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  It is good that you tried to show the expected output, but unfortunately, the 0x7000 number in the expected output does not appear in the input.  This is not a good sign. You also say  you only want the 4 or 8 digits, but then show the `0x` or `x` too. Also, you have a hex prefix but show no digits A-F (or a-f); are they expected too?  The next question is always "What have you tried?" We will help people refine their answers, but generally it is a good idea to show an honest attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response
i want to fetch the device and vendor id
http://forge.voodooprojects.org/p/chameleon/source/tree/2262//trunk/i386/libsaio/gma.h

Answer (score 0):

cat the file thru sed to replace spaces with newline then look for newline (^) followed by x then numeric or (|)  newline (^) followed by  0x the numeric
If you do not want hex (although I suspect that you do I suspect you do) then get rid of the a-fA-F

```
cat yourfilehere | sed -e "s/[ \t]/\n/g" | grep -E "^x[0-9a-fA-F].*|^0x[0-9a-fA-F]*"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Just some comments: 1. `cat | sed` is considered as [UUOC](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#cat). 2. sed to convert spaces & tabs & then piping to grep is also not necessary. You can probably use `grep -o -w`. 3. Unfortunately, the code you posted is not matching OP's requirements. 4 or 8 characters after x...

Comment: I am proud to get an award! 
Point taken though.

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` solution

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/[0-9]*x[0-9]+/) print $i}' file
0x3000
0x80004000
0x7000
0x8600
x1260
x1800
x45003045
```

To make sure it only have 4 or 8 digits after `x` you can do:

```
awk --re-interval '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/[0-9]*x([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{8})$/) print $i}' file
```

Gnu awk needs `--re-interval` to enable interval expressions `{4}`

Answer (score 0):

grep approach:

```
grep -oP '0?x([0-9]{4}){1,2}' test.txt
```

If required,

1. `[0-9]` can be changed to `[0-9a-f]`
2. `-i` option can be added for case insensitivity.

e.g.

```
 $ cat test.txt
 0x3000 0x80004000        # There are Many Random Strings Here#                            0x7000
 0x8600 x1260       x1800 x45003045 # Random Strings #   
 0x123456

 $ grep -oP '0?x([0-9]{4}){1,2}' test.txt
 0x3000
 0x80004000
 0x7000
 0x8600
 x1260
 x1800
 x45003045
 0x1234
```

Comment: But Im Facing This Error on Mac OS X 10.8.5

grep -oP '0?x([0-9]{4}){1,2}' /Users/Jackson/Desktop/gma.txt 

shows


usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoPqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]

Comment: Ok, you did not mention `Mac OS X`. & I do not have OSX to test locally. My first guess would be, there is some issue with use of `{}` syntax. It may need escaping with `\{ ... \}`.